# Is there a way to have App Services settings use Key Vault secrets?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

So we have started to use Azure Key Vault for our secrets, but looks like applications running as Azure App Services have to have application setting values hardcoded in the portal.   Is there a way to have the application settings in App Services pull from Key Vault?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yes you can](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references). By saving app settings value as azure keyvault reference .

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/ec96f02080254f109c51a1f14cdb1931)
```

Please note that your app should have access you can setup using Managed Service Identity (MSI)

Other option is when you use .net is that you can [use extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2#use-a-key-name-prefix) to read settings

Comment: Cool, will give that a try